# How can I use knitr to sort \items?

Tags: itemize, knitr

Using `knitr`, I want to sort `\item`s based on a sorted vector of their values in R. So in the example below, I want the bullets to be printed in numeric order based on `df$value`, not in alphabetical order as they exist now. How can get LaTeX to rearrange them for me?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<echo = FALSE, message = FALSE>>=
library(dplyr)
a = 1; b = 3; c = 4; d = 2
df = data.frame(name = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), value = c(1, 3, 4, 2))
order = arrange(df, value)$name
@

\begin{itemize}
% some code here to rearrange based on \Sexpr{order}...
    \item \Sexpr{a} is the first letter of the alphabet.
    \item \Sexpr{b} is the first letter in "build".
    \item \Sexpr{c} is a decent grade.
    \item \Sexpr{d} stands for dog.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

One point that is important here is that merely calling `\item \Sexpr{order[1]}` is not sufficient because the other text in each `\item` has to be rearranged too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knirt cannot modify the containing LaTeX code. Therefore, you must make the whole list in R. For example, you can make a  R vector of the sorted strings, then add `\item` to each element and show as LaTeX code with the `results="asis"` option.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\begin{document}
R dataframe:
<<echo=F,results='asis',message=F>>=
require(xtable)
df = data.frame(name = c("a","b","c","d"), value = c(1, 3, 4, 2),
comment=c(
  "is the first letter of the alphabet.",
  'is the first letter in “build”.',
  "is a decent grade.",
  "stands for dog."))
xtable(df,digits=0)
@
List of comments in \LaTeX\ by ordered value:
<<echo=F,results='asis'>>=
odf = df[with(df, order(value)), ]
cat("\\begin{itemize}\\item")
cat(paste("\\ordinalnum{",odf$value,
"} (\\texttt{",odf$name,"}) ",odf$comment, sep=""), sep="\n\\item ")
cat("\\end{itemize}")
@
\end{document}
```